# Bitnami WildFly 10.0.1 on Google Compute Engine can't access management interface

Tags: ssh, jboss, wildfly, google-compute-engine, wildfly-10

I have recently launched the Bitnami Wildfly on Google Compute Engine. I have done all the configuration and everythings is working fine except for the management interface which give an error message:

> The management interface could not be loaded.
>
> > Authentication required.

I know i have to create a tunnel via SSH with Putty, I did that and I am able to access the server terminal. The Tunnel i created is to allow connections via localhost:9999 from the remote port 9990.

I have also tried editing standalone.xml and changed the interface to accept connection on , that too did not work.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: It appears that when configuring the tunnel use 127.0.0.1:9990 instead of localhost:9990, I guess this is because the standalone.xml is configured to accept connections on 127.0.0.1.